# Elixir Phoenix: Saving duplicate records in many-many relationship

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am working on a bulksms web app. I created a many-many relationship for group and contacts, I also wrote a function to  but I noticed that each time I submit the form for creating new group, the contacts is saved as duplicates in the contacts table without checking whether the contacts exists or not.

```
defmodule Smsdial.ContactManager.Group do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Ecto.Query, warn: false
  alias Smsdial.Repo
  alias Smsdial.ContactManager.Group
  alias Smsdial.ContactManager.Contact


  schema "groups" do
    field :description, :string
    field :name, :string
    field :contacts, :string
    #field :user_id, :id
    many_to_many :contact, Smsdial.ContactManager.Contact, join_through: 
    Smsdial.ContactManager.Contact_Group
    belongs_to :user, Smsdial.Coherence.User

    timestamps()
  end

  # many-many relationship

  def changeset(%Group{} = group, attr) do
    group
    |> cast(attr, [:name, :description, :contacts])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc(:contact, parse_contact(attr))
  end

  defp parse_contact(attr)  do
    (attr["contacts"] || "")
    |> String.split(",")
    |> Enum.map(&String.trim/1)
    |> Enum.reject(& &1 == "")
    |> insert_and_get_all()
  end

  defp insert_and_get_all([]) do
    []
  end

  defp insert_and_get_all(phones) do
    maps = Enum.map(phones, &%{phone: &1, inserted_at: DateTime.utc_now, 
    updated_at: DateTime.utc_now})
      for c <- maps do
        if c.phone == @contact.phone do
          :contact_already_exist
        else 
          Repo.insert_all Contact, maps, on_conflict: :nothing
          Repo.all(from t in Contact, where: t.phone in ^phones)
      end
  end    
 end 
end
```

That's a snippet of my code. Maybe I can get any suggestion on how to do relationship between contacts and groups in such a way that when I create a group with contacts, the contacts should save directly into the contacts table and flag error if the contact number exist before.

Thank you

Comment: I've added the ecto tag to this question since this really involves ecto as well.

Comment: I'm yet to get a response to this question. Are there no elixir/phoenix developers in this forum, or is the question not clear?

Comment: There are plenty of elixir/phoenix developers on StackOverflow.  I'm not sure that your question is totally clear but that's not my area of deepest expertise either.

Comment: will be helpful if you can simplify your sample code to minimum representation of your problem

Comment: @mikej, I'm running into this exact issue. Did you happen to find a solution?